# html audio element not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, html, html5-audio

So I'm trying to play audio in all browsers it works in all others but anything in iOS. I do understand that iOS doesn't allow auto play but as shown I am using another button to trigger the play.. What am I doing wrong?

```
    audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    audioElement.setAttribute("preload", "none");
    audioElement.setAttribute("id", "audioPlayer");
    document.getElementById("PlayAudio").appendChild(audioElement);
    var source_sound = document.createElement("source");
    audioElement.appendChild(source_sound);
    source_sound.setAttribute("src", 'somefile.php/something.wav');




$("#playButton").click(function (e) {

    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();    
)};
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you get any solution?

Comment: Hey Fernando the solution here is to only set the source of the audio element on click of the play button. Sorry if I'm a little late I've not been on in a while.

Comment: Thank you so much  user3053234